# Substantial delay between in-app purchase of unmanaged item, purchase state change notification

Tags: android, google-play, in-app-purchase, in-app-billing

I have had an app on the Android marketplace with in-app credit purchase ability for many months now. Our #1 issue is users who successfully complete their unmanaged purchase and are billed, but for whatever reason my client app is not recording it to our servers. This doesn't happen 100% of the time, most purchases are executed successfully, and we have very agressive retry logic if a successful purchase can't be uploaded to the server due to connectivity issues or whatever.

Recently we witnessed a scenario where an in-app purchase of an unmanaged item was made, but the onRequestPurchaseResponse method (defined in the sample code [PurchaseObserver.java](http://code.google.com/p/marketbilling/source/browse/src/com/example/dungeons/PurchaseObserver.java), on which our code is based), was not actually called for over 60 seconds.

My suspicion now is that in these cases where successful purchases are not uploaded to our servers, onRequestPurchaseResponse is either never called or the user exits the app before the notification happens because it is so delayed.

I now show a ProgressDialog every time onResume is called after the user returns from the Android Marketplace app, to prevent users from navigating away too quickly and thereby preventing us from recording the purchase.

Can anyone tell me if there are any known bugs involving either delayed or missing notifications from the Android Marketplace app after a successful purchase, and if so, what workarounds you have deployed?

Comment: I have the same issues as you and just came over this article: http://thenextweb.com/mobile/2012/01/05/notable-developer-koush-warns-users-and-devs-against-androids-in-app-purchases/

Comment: Thank you! That article definitely describes what we are seeing

Comment: Hi, I'm the developer in question referenced in that article. For what it's worth, I think unmanaged purchases are more reliable than managed purchases (what I use). I suspect your issue may just be a buggy implementation on your part. :) The bugs were also fixed, according to google, on Dec 22. I have not experienced any new occurrences since.

Comment: Here is the original G+ post: https://plus.google.com/u/0/103583939320326217147/posts/WGQUjMiWoT2

Comment: Also, the market team has supposedly fixed the issues as of Dec 22. I confirmed that my issues stopped after that date. Though the orders that were lost/missing data are still broken.

Comment: It may well be a buggy implementation, thanks for the info RE the fix on December 22. I checked two of my devices and see the latest version of Market is 3.4.4. Do you know if this is the latest version in which the issues were reportedly fixed? Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

A delay is not a bug.  Transaction processing systems are not real-time, and virtually none of the ones with public API's provide a solid guarantee on the amount of time it will take either for a transaction to be processed or for a successful purchase to be reported back to the merchant.

However, I'm not sure I see the issue.  Your app should receive the callback notification at some point in time, so long as the user runs it again eventually.  Assuming, of course, that Google queues its purchase notifications until it is confident that they have been delivered at least once.  Which I would assume they would.

In any case, I think you have a couple of options:

1. Implement your client to always assume that a purchase was successful unless/until it hears otherwise.  Then instead of needing the app to tell the server when a purchase has occurred, you just need it to tell the server when a purchase that you thought occurred did not.  This approach has the same issues with delay as your current approach, but the side-effects are less detrimental to users.
2. Just wait for the notification callback that should come *eventually*, and send it then.  Instead of locking your entire app in an attempt to keep the user from navigating away, just show their purchase with a status of "Pending confirmation from Google" until you get the callback (which, depending upon what the user does, may happen some minutes, hours, or days after the actual purchase).  Then send the information to your server and update the purchase state in app when the send to the server succeeds.

Comment: Agreed that a delay is not a bug; that said, the delay should come in the Android Marketplace app itself and not in the communication between the Android Marketplace app and my client application. Unfortunately it is not possible for my application to assume the transaction was successful, because the server verifies the signature of the transaction. Fundamentally the architecture is flawed - transactions should be happening server-side, not client-side, server-side, client-side, then server side, but that is what Android Marketplace forces apps into.